# Background Repeat not working with absolute position

Tags: html, css

An image is used as background image which is `absolute positioned` it has `repeat-x` property but not working

```
 <div>
    <div class="background-image">
    </div>
 </div>


 .background-image{
       position:absolute;
       background-image : url(...);
       background-repeat: repeat-x;
  }
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Not working as in not repeating, or not visible at all? Does your div have a width and height?

Comment: yes it is 100% width

Comment: `height` is also requierd man . check demo.  http://jsbin.com/haconukavo/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the height of .background-image class and also set the width of container div.

Hopefully this ll helpful

```css
div { 
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.background-image {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu/22/circle-social_facebook_outline_stroke-128.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 130px;
}
```